# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154) - Microsoft DAO 3.6

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is this a problem with compilation for a target processor or DLL registration?

I developed an application in Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition. It references the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library (Interop.DAO.dll). The application runs on XP and 32-bit Vista but on 64-Bit Win7 an exception is raised with the text
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Mohr10.TestUtils' threw an exception. 
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000100-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

The error comes from the source code line

```
   Dim DAODbEngine As New DAO.DBEngine
```

My searches have shown me to look at 2 items:

1. The DLL is 32 bit, so I should compile for Platform x86. The Platform drop-down list on the Compile tab, however, only has "Ative (Any CPU)".
2. I should run regsvr32 interop.dao.dll
   This doesn't work - it gives
   The module "interop.dao.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
   Make sure that "interop.dao.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

The command regasm interop.dao.dll
gives
"Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 2.0.50727.5420
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully"

but the program still doesn't work and regsvr32 gives the same message.

I don't know how to run C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm with the /tlb option because I can't seem to find a .TLB file.

My searches for solutions have remained fruitless, so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Is the Windows 7 machine at Service Pack 1?

Comment: Can you try uninstalling service pack 1 and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Changing from VB2008 Express to VS2010 Professional provided for the required target CPU selection. Compiling for Platform x86 fixed the problem. Thanks!